# Dataset to List poplulation fails when column has null value

Tags: c#, linq, ado.net, dataset

I am trying to convert a Dataset to a List of Object.

Here is what I have tried:

```
List<FundPerformanceRecord> FundPerformanceRecordList 
                            = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(x => new FundPerformanceRecord
                                         {
                                             FundCode = x.Field<string>("FUND_CODE"),
                                             OneMonth = x.Field<decimal>("ROR1MTH"),
                                             ThreeMonth = x.Field<decimal>("ROR3MTH")                                     
                                         })                         
                                .ToList();
```

The class FundPerformanceRecord has the properties defined as Nullable Decimal.

```
    [DataMember]
    public string FundCode;

    [DataMember]
    public decimal? OneMonth;

    [DataMember]
    public decimal? ThreeMonth;
```

I am getting the following error message if any Cell value in the dataset has null value.

```
System error - Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Decimal'. Please use a nullable type.
```

How can I resolve this issue ?

Comment: Have you tried `x.Field<decimal?>()`?

Comment: Nah, it's a direct dupe and should be closed as such. It just took me a minute to find a good target.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360891(v=vs.110).aspx) method supports nullable types, you just have to use them::

```
....
 .Select(x => new FundPerformanceRecord
 {
     FundCode = x.Field<string>("FUND_CODE"),
     OneMonth = x.Field<decimal?>("ROR1MTH"),
     ThreeMonth = x.Field<decimal?>("ROR3MTH")                                     
 })   
....
```

Comment: beat me by 8 seconds!

Answer (score 2):

Your model is has fields that are nullable types `decimal?` but when accessing and casting from the `DataTable` you are using a `decimal` instead of `decimal?`.

Try using `x.Field<decimal?>` as below:

```
List<FundPerformanceRecord> FundPerformanceRecordList 
                            = ds.Tables[0].AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(x => new FundPerformanceRecord
                                         {
                                             FundCode = x.Field<string>("FUND_CODE"),
                                             OneMonth = x.Field<decimal?>("ROR1MTH"),
                                             ThreeMonth = x.Field<decimal?>("ROR3MTH")                                     
                                         })                         
                                .ToList();
```